# Which oracle (10g) template files (DBCA) can be be copied to different server for cloning?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I am trying to clone a schema from one Oracle 10g server to a different Oracle 10g server.

I have created a database template (DBCA) from an existing database (structure and data).

I have copied the three template files `.dbc`, `.DBF` and `.CTL` to the other oracle 10g server. Do I need to copy any other files?

I am looking to achieve this by using DBCA utility not through the import/export data pump.

I can clone a database on the same machine using DBCA utility but am not able to clone it on the different machine using the first machine's template.

Comment: I am looking to achieve this by using DBCA utility not through import/export data pump.

Comment: Just get the pfile from the other database, edit proper paths. Create a spfile from the pfile ( http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/pfile_spfile.htm )